# Laravel finding where two tables have matching values and displaying both to the view

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, web-development-server

Ok so the two tables are for a customer and a job associated with that customer. Both of the tables (jobs,customers) have location ids that links the two. In the view I am displaying all the jobs in a table which also includes that customers address. I have tried in the controller but it is saying "Property [location_number] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.". This is my Controller Method:

```
public function search_job(Request $request){



    if($request->class == '' && $request->status == '' && $request->type == '' && $request->department == '' && $request->start_date == '' && $request->end_date == '' && $request->last_called == '')
    {
        $jobs = Job::where('class','LIKE','%'."none".'%');
        // return view('callCenter.ccJobSearch' ,['jobs'=>$jobs]);
        $custs = Customer::where('location_number',$jobs->location_number)->get();

        return view('callCenter.ccJobSearch',['jobs'=>$jobs,'custs'=>$custs]);
    }
    else
    {
        if($request->start_date ==NULL)
        {
            $request->start_date = date("01-01-1970");
        }
        if($request->end_date ==NULL)
        {
            $request->end_date = date("m-d-Y");
        }
        if($request->last_called ==NULL)
        {
            $request->last_called = date("m-d-Y");
        }

        $jobs = Job::where('class','LIKE','%'.$request->class.'%')
                    ->where('job_status','LIKE','%'.$request->status.'%')
                    ->where('type','LIKE','%'.$request->type.'%')
                    ->where('department','LIKE','%'.$request->department.'%')
                    ->whereBetween('date_booked',[$request->start_date, $request->end_date])
                    ->whereBetween('date_last_called',['01-01-1970',$request->last_called])->get();

        $custs = Customer::where('location_number',$jobs->location_number)->get();

        return view('callCenter.ccJobSearch',['jobs'=>$jobs,'custs'=>$custs]);
    }
    


}
```

and this the part of my view where I try to access those arrays:

```
                                @foreach($jobs as $job)
                                <tr class="bg-white lg:hover:bg-gray-100 flex lg:table-row flex-row lg:flex-row flex-wrap lg:flex-no-wrap mb-10 lg:mb-0">
                         
                                    <td class="w-full lg:w-auto p-1 text-gray-800 text-center border border-b block lg:table-cell relative lg:static">
                                        <span class="lg:hidden absolute top-0 left-0 bg-blue-200 px-dispatch.2 py-1 text-xs font-bold uppercase"></span>
                                        <div class="flex items-center">
                                            <div class="ml-4">
                                                <div class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">
                                                    {{$job->job_number}}
                                                    
                                                </div>
                                    
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="w-full lg:w-auto p-1 text-gray-800 text-center border border-b block lg:table-cell relative lg:static text-xs">
                                        <span class="lg:hidden absolute top-0 left-0 bg-blue-200 px-dispatch.2 py-1 text-xs font-bold uppercase"></span>
                                        {{$job->type}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="w-full lg:w-auto p-1 text-gray-800 text-center border border-b block lg:table-cell relative lg:static text-xs">
                                        <span class="lg:hidden absolute top-0 left-0 bg-blue-200 px-dispatch.2 py-1 text-xs font-bold uppercase"></span>
                                        {{$job->department}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="w-full lg:w-auto p-1 text-gray-800 text-center border border-b block lg:table-cell relative lg:static text-xs">
                                        <span class="lg:hidden absolute top-0 left-0 bg-blue-200 px-dispatch.2 py-1 text-xs font-bold uppercase"></span>
                                        {{$job->billing_number}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="w-full lg:w-auto p-1 text-gray-800 text-center border border-b block lg:table-cell relative lg:static text-xs">
                                        <span class="lg:hidden absolute top-0 left-0 bg-blue-200 px-dispatch.2 py-1 text-xs font-bold uppercase"></span>
                                        {{$job->location_number}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="w-full lg:w-auto p-1 text-gray-800 text-center border border-b block lg:table-cell relative lg:static text-xs">
                                        <span class="lg:hidden absolute top-0 left-0 bg-blue-200 px-dispatch.2 py-1 text-xs font-bold uppercase"></span>
                                        {{$cust->last_name}}
                                    
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="w-full lg:w-auto p-1 text-gray-800 text-center border border-b block lg:table-cell relative lg:static text-xs">
                                        <span class="lg:hidden absolute top-0 left-0 bg-blue-200 px-dispatch.2 py-1 text-xs font-bold uppercase"></span>
                                        {{$job->date_booked}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="w-full lg:w-auto p-1 text-gray-800 text-center border border-b block lg:table-cell relative lg:static text-xs">
                                        <span class="lg:hidden absolute top-0 left-0 bg-blue-200 px-dispatch.2 py-1 text-xs font-bold uppercase"></span>
                                        {{$job->job_status}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="w-full lg:w-auto p-1 text-gray-800 text-center border border-b block lg:table-cell relative lg:static text-xs">
                                        <span class="lg:hidden absolute top-0 left-0 bg-blue-200 px-dispatch.2 py-1 text-xs font-bold uppercase"></span>
                                        {{$job->tech}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="w-full lg:w-auto p-1 text-gray-800 text-center border border-b block lg:table-cell relative lg:static text-xs">
                                        <span class="lg:hidden absolute top-0 left-0 bg-blue-200 px-dispatch.2 py-1 text-xs font-bold uppercase"></span>
                                        {{$job->class}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="w-full lg:w-auto p-1 text-gray-800 text-center border border-b block lg:table-cell relative lg:static text-xs">
                                        <span class="lg:hidden absolute top-0 left-0 bg-blue-200 px-dispatch.2 py-1 text-xs font-bold uppercase"></span>
                                        {{$custs->street_address}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="w-full lg:w-auto p-1 text-gray-800 text-center border border-b block lg:table-cell relative lg:static text-xs">
                                        <span class="lg:hidden absolute top-0 left-0 bg-blue-200 px-dispatch.2 py-1 text-xs font-bold uppercase"></span>
                                        {{$custs->city}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="w-full lg:w-auto p-1 text-gray-800 text-center border border-b block lg:table-cell relative lg:static text-xs">
                                        <span class="lg:hidden absolute top-0 left-0 bg-blue-200 px-dispatch.2 py-1 text-xs font-bold uppercase"></span>
                                        {{$custs->state}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="w-full lg:w-auto p-1 text-gray-800 text-center border border-b block lg:table-cell relative lg:static text-xs">
                                        <span class="lg:hidden absolute top-0 left-0 bg-blue-200 px-dispatch.2 py-1 text-xs font-bold uppercase"></span>
                                        {{$custs->zip}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="w-full lg:w-auto p-1 text-gray-800 text-center border border-b block lg:table-cell relative lg:static text-xs">
                                        <span class="lg:hidden absolute top-0 left-0 bg-blue-200 px-dispatch.2 py-1 text-xs font-bold uppercase"></span>
                                        {{$custs->phone_number_1}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="w-full lg:w-auto p-1 text-gray-800 text-center border border-b block lg:table-cell relative lg:static text-xs">
                                        <span class="lg:hidden absolute top-0 left-0 bg-blue-200 px-dispatch.2 py-1 text-xs font-bold uppercase"></span>
                                        {{$job->happy_check_by}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="w-full lg:w-auto p-1 text-gray-800 text-center border border-b block lg:table-cell relative lg:static text-xs">
                                        <span class="lg:hidden absolute top-0 left-0 bg-blue-200 px-dispatch.2 py-1 text-xs font-bold uppercase"></span>
                                        {{$job->type}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="w-full lg:w-auto p-1 text-gray-800 text-center border border-b block lg:table-cell relative lg:static text-xs">
                                        <span class="lg:hidden absolute top-0 left-0 bg-blue-200 px-dispatch.2 py-1 text-xs font-bold uppercase"></span>
                                        {{$job->type}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="w-full lg:w-auto p-1 text-gray-800 text-center border border-b block lg:table-cell relative lg:static text-xs">
                                        <button class="text-gray-500 bg-yellow-200 border border-solid border-gray-500 hover:bg-yellow-400 hover:text-white active:bg-pink-600 font-bold uppercase text-base px-2 py-1 rounded outline-none focus:outline-none mr-1 mb-1 ease-linear transition-all duration-150" type="button">
                                            <i class="far fa-sticky-note"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="w-full lg:w-auto p-1 text-gray-800 text-center border border-b block lg:table-cell relative lg:static text-xs">
                                        <button class="text-white bg-blue-300 border border-solid border-gray-500 hover:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white active:bg-pink-600 font-bold uppercase text-xs px-4 py-2 rounded outline-none focus:outline-none mr-1 mb-1 ease-linear transition-all duration-150" type="button"  onclick="window.open('http://localhost:8000/callCenter/ccJobInfo');">
                                            Info
                                        </button>
                                    </td>
                                    
                                </tr>
                                @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `->get()` on `$jobs = Job::where('class','LIKE','%'."none".'%');`

Otherwise you just have a query builder instance.

Comment: Good catch. The `if` condition on the controller doesn't call `->get()`.

Comment: @DanielBurgess, And there is also typo on the view that needs to be corrected. You are accessing `$custs`. I am assuming your are already on the `$custs` loop, so you have to use `$cust`. The `state` , `zip`, `phone_number_1` are all using `$custs`